# How to share variables data in two firebase functions nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to share the value of the variable assigned by function 1 inside of function 2.

but these values are missing.
here's how I'm doing:

> 

```
var a;

exports.funA= functions.pubsub.schedule("every 45 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
  a=30;
  return null;
});


exports.funB= functions.pubsub.schedule("every 15 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
console.log(a);   //it prints undefined even after 45 minutes passed
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec):

> ... invocations might be handled by different function instances,
> which don’t share global variables, memory, file systems, or other
> state.

Basically the functions execute independent of each other and don't share state. You can pass data between the two using an HTTP endpoint or Pub/Sub, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059951/how-to-pass-data-between-firebase-cloud-functions).